# Validating a std::vector<std::string> member of an object using GMock

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I am new to GTest/Gmock.
Below is a class:

```
class HttpRequest
{
   public:
   std::string name;
   std::vector<std::string> headers;

   HttpRequest()
   {
        name = "HTTP"
        headers.push_back( "ZERO" );
        headers.push_back( "ONE" );
        headers.push_back( "TWO" );
   }
   virtual ~HttpRequest();
}
```

When trying to use the below EXPECT_CALL function for validating the member of this object using GTest/Gmock as below, I get the error `error C2228: left of '.at' must have class/struct/union`

```
EXPECT_CALL ( requestHandler, Send(
AllOf(Field(&HttpRequest::name, "HTTP"),
     Field(&HttpRequest::headers.at(0), "ZERO")
     )
  )).Times(1);
```

Any inputs/suggestions would be very helpful, Thank you.

Comment: What are your test conditions?

Comment: `&HttpRequest::headers` is a pointer-to-member, not an object. You cannot call a member function on a pointer-to-member, it has no members.

Comment: @Jonathan makes a good point: you can't call a method on a pointer-to-member, you need to [define your own matcher](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CheatSheet#Defining_Matchers) instead. Also, what's the signature of the `Send()` method? It's not declared in the class.